# Integration of multiple functions involved

Tags: calculus

Given that $f(y)=e^{y}$ and $g(y)=y$ where $y>0$.  If 
$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(t-y)g(y)dy$ ,then how could we evaluate $F(t)$?

Comment: Seems like convolution one other interesting way could be to multiply Laplace transform of both and take it's inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
  F(t) &= \int_{0}^{t} e^{t-y} y \, dy \\
  &= [y(-e^{t-y})]_{0}^{t}-\int_{0}^{t} (-e^{t-y}) dy \\
  &= -t+\int_{0}^{t} e^{t-y} dy \\
  &= -t+[-e^{t-y}]_{0}^{t} \\
  &= e^{t}+1-t
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\int xe^x \:dx$

Integration by parts

$\int xe^x \:dx = xe^x - \int e^x \:dx$